# How to concatenate string with brackets in Swift 2

Tags: swift

How to concatenate string with brackets in Swift 2

in simple i know how to concatenate the string but if i want to brackets inside the string

```
    let a = "Hello"
    let b = "World"
    let first = "(a) Per Level (b)" // i want to show this output ?
```

output would be like this : (Hello) Per Level (World)

Answer (score 4):

Another format you can use with the latest Swift2:

```
let first = "(\(a)) Per Level (\(b))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let first = String(format: "(%@) Per Level (%@)", a, b)
```

Comment: Or use String interpolation: `let first = "(\(a)) Per Level (\(b))"`

Comment: Yes indeed @vacawama ! i_am_jorm used the more obj c way